# Populate doesn't return specified collection data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this credit schema

```
const CreditSchema = new Schema({
  userId: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  credit: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  log: [String]
})
```

I hope it can be retrieve in below call

```
exports.getUser = async function(req, res) {

  const user = await User.findOne({_id: req.query.id})
  .populate('credit')
  .exec()

  res.json(user)
}
```

But what I get is userSchema's data, I don't see the data from credit schema. This is how my userSchema look like

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  credit: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    ref: 'Credit'
  }
})
```

I really scratch my head, I have the data in my db and the `_id` of userSchema is the same with `userId` of creditSchema.

This is the data of User and Credit

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do the actual documents for User and the referenced Credit look like?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
 User.findOne({_id: req.query.id})
.populate("credit")
.exec(function (err: any, result: any) {
    ...//code    
})
});
```

Comment: this doesn't make any difference, I'm using await instead of callback style.